# Is collapse toolbar option available in ckeditor -5 , like previous version

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar, ckeditor5

Is collapse toolbar option available in ckeditor -5 , like previous version. Its available in previous versions and now its not there in documentation.

collapse toolbar option available in ckeditor -5